# Import Coordinates from a Microsoft SQL Server database to Angular Google Maps API

Tags: sql-server, angular, database, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database with customers data:

```
Name,
City,
Details,
Latitude 
Longitude
```

And I have an Angular application with Google Maps API implemented.

I want to add markers directly from the database to my map. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need an web API to return list or array of Latitudes  nd Longitudes. Next step is, in angular you have to install @angular/google-maps

```
npm i @angular/google-maps
```

After that, you can write the code below in ts file after get data from API:

```
apiResult.forEach(item => {
      this.markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: item.Latitude,
          lng: item.Longitude
        },
        draggable: false,
        label: item.Name
      }));
    });
```

Finally, you should add the code below in HTML.

```
           <google-map [zoom]="markerZoom" height="400px" width="100%" [center]="markerCenter">
                <map-marker #markerElem="mapMarker" *ngFor="let marker of markers" [label]="marker.label"
                    [position]="marker.position" [options]="marker">
                </map-marker>
                <map-info-window *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position">Hello Google Maps
                </map-info-window>
            </google-map>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, I already have an API, but I call a list of customers at once and I present them on a mat-table.

From there I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude to implement on the google map.

Comment: I could not understand. You asked for how to show locations on the map so as I mentioned earlier you just call the API to get the data. After that put the data in this.markers array. Finally, write the html code. It will show the locations on the map. Just install @angular/google-maps before all of them

Comment: So still you have locations data you can do the same thing

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself badly.
From the table where I present the clients, I want to select the ones I want to show on the map through checkboxes.

Comment: it does not matter. You still have the data in an array which you are iterating it to show data in table or bind it etc. on click of checkbox then click an button you can select  latitude and longitude and display them on google map.